# Is it possible to stop a user closing a wpf/C# application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that uploads a picture to my website. While uploading I would like to temporarily disable the user from closing the program. Is there a way to do this? by either temporarily disabling the close button or by intercepting the close call?

Comment: Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7717394/632337) to intercept the close call.

Comment: Just remember a process kill is possible.

Comment: @RohitVats Wow that was incredibly simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Window.WindowStyle` property. I also suggest to don't display the window in the Taskbar.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Background="AliceBlue" WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="False" >

</Window>
```

Anyway, be aware that is not possible to stop a user to close your program, as long as he can access to the Task Manager.