# C# WPF - ApplicationExit calling an API

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I have to call an API when my WPF Applications is being closed.

I'm using `Application_Exit` event because I have to do this even closing all the windows, being shut down from **Task Manager** or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

I've tried several ways, but all the options has some issues (some of them are these):

OPTION A: Async event + `await`

```cs
private async void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    if (MonitorInstance.Instance.User != null)
    {
        Log.Information($"Disconnect starting");
        var result = await _apiClient.Disconnect();
        Log.Information($"Disconnect result: {result}");
    }
}
```

This option just calls the HTTP CONNECT (which sometimes succeed and others is being cancelled) but not my PATCH request.

OPTION B: Blocking Thread with `Result` of Task.

```cs
private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    if (MonitorInstance.Instance.User != null)
    {
        Log.Information($"Disconnect starting");
        var result = _apiClient.Disconnect().Result;
        Log.Information($"Disconnect result: {result}");
    }
}
```

This effectively calls the API but the process continues running. Visual Studio continues showing that the App is running and this is not desired.

I think it's worth to mention that I'm calling the API (which uses SSL) using `HttpClient` which is being created in the `Disconnect` method and I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

My questions:

1. Is `Application_Exit` the proper event to do this?
2. How to program the `Application_Exit` event to fulfill all the scenarios?
3. Should I change the implementation for my call to do it directly without the `HttpClient`?

Comment: Maybe there's an `await` without `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your API client?

Comment: @Marcos Frank - [Handle a WPF Exit Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717222/handle-a-wpf-exit-event)

Comment: @KevinGosse thanks for your response. I'm not using ConfigureAwait(false).

Comment: @Jackdaw thanks for your response. So you're suggesting me Stop all my windows for closing (or detect if all of them were closed), make the API call and then closing my application? I was thinking in a more centralized solution. But I will try that.

Comment: @MarcosFrank Well you should, you're running into a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

This a classic case of deadlock. Your code is running under a synchronization context, your `await` calls inside of `_apiClient.Disconnect()` try to resume on the UI thread, but the UI thread is blocked waiting synchronously on the task because of `.Result`.

There are multiple ways to get around that, but for your precise case I don't think it's useful to get fancy. Just use `Task.Run` to run your call in a safer context:

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    if (MonitorInstance.Instance.User != null)
    {
        Log.Information($"Disconnect starting");
        var result = Task.Run(apiClient.Disconnect).Result;
        Log.Information($"Disconnect result: {result}");
    }
}
```