# How can I stop the docker engine running integrated on WSL2 from the command line?

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, shutdown, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I run WSL2 on Windows with an Ubuntu distribution inside WSL, and Docker desktop using the integrated "WSL2-based engine".

If I do `wsl --shutdown` in the CLI, Docker Desktop complains about the backend shutting down unexpectedly.

What command should I issue before the `wsl --shutdown` to shutdown the Docker engine without danger of loosing data?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6122 by manually setting

**wslEngineEnabled** from **true** to **false** in the docker setting file

**C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json**

In case the AppData does not show, watch this
https://youtu.be/9OO6sgvq2Aw

Comment: When you just want to disable WSL support for a single distro, use the `integratedWslDistros` setting (just remove the name of the distro from the array)

Answer (score 0):

> What command should I issue before the `wsl --shutdown` to shutdown the Docker engine without danger of loosing data?

I'm not sure about a "command" (which would be nice, since I prefer keyboard interaction over the mouse for most things), but at the moment I'm just using the GUI.  To make sure that Docker Desktop is *safely* shut down, I go to the Windows Taskbar icon (usually in "Hidden Icons"/overflow, unless you've configured it otherwise), right-click, and *Quit Docker Desktop*.

There may be a way to script it.  I did try `taskkill` (without) the `/f` (force) option, but that didn't work.

It sounds like [`rmlogotest.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65392006/11810933), which is a tool for sending Windows shutdown messages to applications might work.

Answer (score 0):

In C:\Users\YourUsername dir create .wslconfig

[wsl2]
memory=GB

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).